# Python: Sorting a csv file by intervals

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file in that type:

```
45,85,{20, 58, 12, ...},]-inf;503]  
478,10,{5, 16, 87, ...},]1137;1212]    
etc.
```

I need to sort the file by the last column meaning the thing between brackets. These numbers between backets are minutes in a day, the 24 hours has been split in 7 intervals of minutes, from ]-inf;503] to ]1212;+inf].

I thought I managed it, but when I looked at the file it was wrong.
Here is what I got so far:

```
data = csv.reader(open('Document.txt'))

sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(6))

with open('sorted1.txt', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames1=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']
    writing=csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames1)
    for line in sortedlist:
        writing.writerow({'0': line[0] ,'1': line[1] ,'2': line[2] ,'3': line[3] ,'4': line[4] ,'5': line[5] ,'6': line[6]})


f.close()
```

The output result should be the document, sorted, without the headers. But my file is not sorted, I mean every time intervals are together meaning the ]-inf;503] are all together and so on, but not sorted correctly. Also every line in my output file has a blank line between them and I need these empty lines gone.
Where did I do wrong?

Comment: your key here is wrong, you want your key function to transform your time encoding to a simply integer that `sort` can compare, i cant tell you how to do it as i dont understand your encoding. also note that if your file contains headers you will be sorting them as well, you can avoid that by doing `next(data)` once

Comment: So you mean that `key=operator.itemgetter(6)` is wrong? But how else can I tell my program to sort by that column then?

Comment: it need to be more coplex than that. you fetch the correct item, but python does know how to compare that in a way that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not clever enough to guess that the *thing between bracket* is a range. For the interpretor it is just a string and it will sort it in lexicographic order.

So you need a dedicated  key function to sort your ranges by their first value, the string `'-inf'` being smaller than any number. It could be:

```
def keyfunc(row):
    start = row[6]
    ix = start.index(';')      # stop before the semicolon
    start = start[1:ix]        # and start after the initial bracket
    return -1 if start == '-inf' else int(start)
```

For the write part, the documentation states that the file should be opened with `newline=''`, and you have overthought the whole thing. It could be as simple as:

```
data = csv.reader(open('Document.txt'))

sortedlist = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)

with open('sorted1.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writing=csv.writer(f)
    writing.writerows(sortedlist)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I get now why it didn't work in the first place.